# How to include keywords in default searched properties

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, keyword

I understand that with standard searching in SharePoint Online I need to add "keywords:" to my search query to search by keywords (ex. "keywords: Ford" when looking for all items tagged as "Ford" on a site about cars).  However, I don't want the users to have to remember this syntax and I would prefer that they could type the keywords directly in the search (ex. "Ford") and have the keywords be included in the default properties that are searched.  How can I do this with SharePoint Online?  I'm unable to edit the "Searchable" checkbox of the "Keywords" property.  I've tried using a RefinableString but that too does not let me change the "Searchable" checkbox.

Note - Using search refiners is not the solution though I've seen it mentioned in many articles.  Search refiners only let you narrow down existing results by using keywords.  They do not allow you to search by keyword.

---

### Update

I was able to implement Matthew McDermott's solution

**Built-In Search**

[image: Built-In Search]

**Manage Query Rules**

[image: Manage Query Rules]

**Query Rule**

[image: Query Rule]

**Result Block**

[image: Query Rule]

**Search w/Result Block**

[image: Search w/Result Block]

Comment: Have you tried Query Rules or do you just want to make a global change for all users and all queries?

Comment: @MatthewMcDermott Do you have any links for a tutorial on how to use Query Rules w/keywords?  I'm playing around with it right now but like all things SharePoint it's not very intuitive.

Comment: You can start here with 75 minutes on the topic. http://www.ableblue.com/blog/archive/2014/03/08/spc322-sharepoint-search-display-templates-and-query-rules/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a Query Rule that has no condition. Add a Result Block and then run the query like: `Keywords:"{subjectTerms}"`.

The query will only show if there are results from their query.

Comment: What do you mean "The query will only show if there are results from their query"?  Does that mean if the main query has 0 results then this additional result block will not show any results even if there are some?

Comment: No, it means that the Result Block will only show if there are results matching the Query.

Answer (score 0):

Go to SharePoint Admin Center > Search > Manage Search Schema

- Select **New Managed Property**
- Add a **Property Name** (e.g. CustomKeywords)
- Select the following **Main Characteristics** (Searchable, Queryable, Retrievable, and Allow multiple values)
- Select **Add a Mapping** in the **Mappings to crawled properties** section
- Search for the crawled property name field using the text "keyword"
- Select the **ows_Keywords** crawled property and then select **OK**
- You may want repeat the previous step to add additional crawled properties depending on your configuration (e.g. the "Keywords" crawled property).
- Select **OK** again to create the new managed property
- Go to the settings of a list or library you're trying to search
- Select **Advanced Settings** and then the **Reindex** option and confirm the dialog about potential performance impacts.
- Select **OK** and wait a few minutes
- Keywords should be searchable now